# ElasticDump transform

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am new to elastic search. I have to copy the index from one ElasticSearch server to another ES Server and I have to update some field values before inserting them into the destination server. I found we can use the elasticdump npm package but there are no examples found how to use the transform option provided by the elasticdump package. can someone please provide an example to use the transform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Elasticdump, you can migrate data from one cluster to another. You can also use Logstash or [remote reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html#reindex-from-remote). But it's not possible to manipulate the data during migration with elasticdump.

You can use [ingest_pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html#set-default-pipeline), and ingest the data while indexing in the destination cluster.

I recommend you use remote reindex and ingest_pipeline like the following.

**[#create an ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html)**

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "my-long-field",
        "value": 10
      }
    },
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "my-boolean-field",
        "value": true
      }
    },
    {
      "lowercase": {
        "field": "my-keyword-field"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

#reindex the data

```
POST _reindex
{
  "source": {
    "remote": {
      "host": "http://otherhost:9200",
      "username": "user",
      "password": "pass"
    },
    "index": "my-index-000001"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "my-new-index-000001",
    "pipeline": "my-pipeline"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to manipulate data during migration with elasticdump. Given a file such as `transform.json` with contents

```
module.exports = function(doc,options) {
  doc._source.someProperty = 'some value';
  console.log(doc);
  return doc;
}
```

you can run `elasticdump ... --transform='@./transform.js'` and the the log will look something like

```
{
  ...
  _source: {
    ...
    someProperty: 'some value'
  }
}
```

and all the migrated documents will have the added property.